# How to add newline into error messages from "exec" command in tcl

Tags: linux, tcl

I am trying to execute a binary file (generated by C code) through TCL "exec" command. This binary throws exception after executing some code and printing some output. I want to see those error messages printed by binary, but all the error messages are coming into one single line after deleting newline charecter.

I have already tried -keepnewline and -ignorestderr switches in exec commands but nothing comes to rescue.

This is how I am executing the binary
    exec abc.out
I have tried
    exec -keepnewline -ignorestderr abc.out

C file (from which binary is generated) contains some 100 printf statements, each followed by newline characters. But all newline characters are deleted by exec and all 100 lines are coming in one single line. I guess all messages are going into std error, while deletes newline characters, but not sure. Is there a way by which I can have all messages in different line.

Comment: Did you search for previous Q&A regarding `exec` and standard channels? There are plenty of those available for an initial read. Also, you might want to give concrete examples of those printed lines (what do you see? what do you expect?).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` of the child process to the parent (Tcl) process:

```
exec >@ stdout 2>@ stderr abc.out
```